# How do I change the expression of a object variable in the form of "24 years 7 months" to simply a float value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am relatively new to pandas and dataframes , so I have a datable **df_Jan** as follow:
[image]

As you can see , the value for the column *remaining_lease* is in the form of "XX years XX months" and the *remaining_lease* variable has a data type of object. I want to be able to change the data to float and I am not really sure how to do it.

I have tried

```
df_Jan['remaining_lease'].astype('float')
```

but this happened:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it manually:

```
years = df_Jan['remaining_lease'].str.split().str[0].astype(float)
months = df_Jan['remaining_lease'].str.split().str[2].astype(float) / 12
df_Jan['remaining_lease'] = years + months
```